# How to send image picked with image_picker from child widget to his parent?

Tags: flutter, callback, imagepicker

I'm trying to send a picture selected with image_picker from child to his parent, the child widget is PhotoPicker and the parent is UpdateInformationScreen.
For that I've tried to use a callback but the **File _deviceImage** is null outside _pickImage method and I don't know why.

**Inside _pickImage, _deviceImage is not null:**

```
Future _pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    try {
      XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);

      if (pickedFile != null) {
        setState(() {
          _deviceImage = File(pickedFile.path);
          print("_device 1: $_deviceImage"); // <--------------------------- Not null
        });
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      Utils.showErrorMessage(e.message);
    }
  }
```

**But in the onPressed it's null**

```
TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                _pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                widget.onImageSelected(_deviceImage);
                print("_device 2: $_deviceImage"); // <--------------------------- Null
              }, // => _pickImage(ImageSource.gallery),
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.photo,
                size: 30,
                color: googleButtonTextColor,
              ),
              label: const Text(
                gallery,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: googleButtonTextColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Child widget:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/constant/text.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../constant/color.dart';
import '../model/instructor.dart';

class PhotoPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(File?) onImageSelected;

  const PhotoPicker({Key? key, required this.onImageSelected}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PhotoPicker> createState() => _PhotoPickerState();
}

class _PhotoPickerState extends State<PhotoPicker> {
  File? _deviceImage;

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //----------------------- Pick image from gallery or camera ------------------
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Future _pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    try {
      XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);

      if (pickedFile != null) {
        setState(() {
          _deviceImage = File(pickedFile.path);
          print("_device 1: $_deviceImage"); <--------------------------- Not null
        });
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      Utils.showErrorMessage(e.message);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final instructor = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Instructor;

    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          child: _deviceImage != null
          ? CircleAvatar(
              radius: 90,
              backgroundImage: Image.file(
                _deviceImage!,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ).image
          )
          : CircleAvatar(
            radius: 90,
            backgroundImage: instructor.photo != null
                ? NetworkImage(instructor.photo.toString())
                : const AssetImage(
                "assets/images/no_photo.jpg"
            )
            as ImageProvider,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 20,),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                _pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                widget.onImageSelected(_deviceImage);
                print("_device 2: $_deviceImage");
              }, // => _pickImage(ImageSource.gallery),
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.photo,
                size: 30,
                color: googleButtonTextColor,
              ),
              label: const Text(
                gallery,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: googleButtonTextColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                _pickImage(ImageSource.camera);
                widget.onImageSelected(_deviceImage); <--------------------------- Null
              },//=> _pickImage(ImageSource.camera),
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.photo_camera,
                size: 30,
                color: googleButtonTextColor,
              ),
              label: const Text(
                camera,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: googleButtonTextColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The parent widget:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/view/information_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/widget/photo_picker.dart';
import 'package:intl_phone_field/intl_phone_field.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../constant/color.dart';
import '../constant/text.dart';
import '../model/instructor.dart';
import '../provider/instructor_view_model.dart';

class UpdateInformationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String ROUTE_NAME = "/updateInformation";

  const UpdateInformationScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UpdateInformationScreen> createState() =>
      _UpdateInformationScreenState();
}

class _UpdateInformationScreenState extends State<UpdateInformationScreen> {
  final firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  final phoneNumberController = TextEditingController();
  String? phoneNumber;
  File? photo;

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------- Free memory allocated to the existing variables ----------------
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  @override
  void dispose() {
    firstNameController.dispose();
    phoneNumberController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final instructor = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Instructor;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, InformationScreen.ROUTE_NAME);
          },
        ),
        title: const Text(appTitle),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 20,),
            PhotoPicker(
              onImageSelected: (image) {
                print("Image up: $image"); <--------------------------- Null
                setState(() {
                  photo = image;
                  print("Image up set state: $photo");
                });
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20,),
            //----------------------------- First name -------------------------
            TextField(
              controller: firstNameController,
              cursorColor: cursorColor,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: const Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: grey,
                  size: 30,
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.5),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.orange),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.5),
                ),
                labelText: instructor.firstName != null
                    ? instructor.firstName.toString()
                    : updateFirstnameText,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            //----------------------------- Phone number -----------------------
            IntlPhoneField(
              controller: phoneNumberController,
              initialValue: instructor.phoneNumber != null
                  ? Utils.phoneNumberWithoutCountryCode(instructor.phoneNumber.toString())
                  : phoneSignInLabelText,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: instructor.phoneNumber != null
                    ? Utils.phoneNumberWithoutCountryCode(instructor.phoneNumber.toString())
                    : phoneSignInLabelText,
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(),
                ),
              ),
              initialCountryCode: 'FR',
              onChanged: (phone) {
                phoneNumber = phone.completeNumber;
                print(phone.completeNumber);
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            //----------------------------- Update button ----------------------
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _clickOnUpdateInformationButton(
                    context,
                    instructor.uid!,
                    //----------------------------- First name -----------------
                    firstNameController.text.isNotEmpty
                    ? firstNameController.text.trim()
                    : instructor.firstName!,
                    //----------------------------- Phone number ---------------
                    phoneNumberController.text.isNotEmpty
                    ? phoneNumber!
                    : instructor.phoneNumber!,
                );
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                fixedSize: const Size(double.infinity, 50),
                primary: cursorColor,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                ),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: const [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 100),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.update,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    updateInfoButton,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //----------------------------- Click on update information button -----------
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  void _clickOnUpdateInformationButton(BuildContext context, String uid, String firstName, String phoneNumber) {
    final instructorViewModel = Provider.of<InstructorViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    instructorViewModel.updateInstructor(uid, firstName, phoneNumber);
    Utils.goToInformationScreen(context);
    Utils.showSuccessMessage(updateInformationSuccessText);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onPressed` like this. The problem is  image file picked inside method and ui is not waiting for this method complete it's job. `await` keyword used to wait for operation result. For more, search about asynchronous programming in dart.

```
onPressed: () async {
                await _pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                widget.onImageSelected(_deviceImage);
                print("_device 2: $_deviceImage"); // <--------------------------- Null
              }, // => _pickImage(ImageSource.gallery),
```